# Determining 'Addictive' or 'multiplicative' seasonality and its forecast accuracy

Tags: python, accuracy, forecasting

Let's say that I have a "train" and "test" set data, how do I determine if my train set follows "additive" or "multiplicative" seasonality? Do I fit just the data with both seasonality and forecast the outcome? Also how do I check the associated accuracy with each of them?

"Write a function or list of steps, that returns which seasonality is more accurate for an ‘h’ horizon forecast and the associated accuracy."

Does anyone also know what does 'h' horizon forecast mean?

Answer (score 0):

The horizon forecast means how many days ahead you are able to predict.

I don't know what 'additive' or 'multiplicative' means, but you can make linear or non-linear predictions with different algorithms.

For instance, a [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) vs a [polynomial regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/polynomial-regression-with-scikit-learn-what-you-should-know-bed9d3296f2).

Seasonality detection depends on the algorithm you use. Neural networks like [LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) or models like [SARIMA](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sarima-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/) can find patterns quite easily.

Comment: In this question, does it mean that I have to choose a 'h' horizon like 30 days? If I use the SARIMA, how do I test the accuracy of the diff seasonality?

Comment: A horizon of a few days is generally enough for most models. The accuracy could be calculated with many methods. The most common one is 1-(predicted_value/real_value), because the closer it is to 0, the better it is.

Comment: If it is a data of 5 years, would you use 5 days horizon for it? The formula for accuracy is great, I appreciate!

Comment: One day is good enough for a start. If the predictions are satisfactory, you can increase.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.